# How to pass value from on child window to another

Tags: javascript

I want to pass value from child window2 to child window1.I have use the code but it is passing value in parent window.My code is below here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function post_value(){
     var val='5';
     window.opener.document.getElementById('barcode1txt').value=val; 
     self.close();
  }
```

What will change in this code if i want to pass this value between two child windows.Please guide me.Thanks

Comment: the two child windows don't know of each other, so you'll have to pass it via parent window. You already do the first step. Now - in parent window - react on the value change (via an onchange listenerer) and pass it to the other child.

Comment: how does this relate to PHP?

Comment: @jeff can you share any link for help.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping to understand your question, there is a mainframe (window.top) and two (same domain?) iFrames that will have to communicate between each other.

So there are a few ways to get this done.
Assuming you have samedomain frames you can access window.top from you can do something like this in the mainframe:

```
<script>
var frame1 = document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow;
var frame2 = document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow;
</script>
```

Now you can easily define anything by this reference, you could do this from frame2 to define a method in frame1:

```
<script>
window.top.frame1.demoalert = function() {alert()};
</script>
```

After this you can invoke demoalert directly from frame1.
You can define or transport anything that way from frame2 to frame1, but you have to go by the parent and make sure you finde frame1 from the view of the parent.

Starting in frame2 you would do that:

```
<script>
function post_value(){
    let frame1 = window.top.document.getElementByid('frame1').contentWindow;
    let val='5';
    frame1.document.getElementById('barcode1txt').value=val; 
    self.close();
}
post_value()
</script>
```

For iFrames not allowed to access the parent, their will be a way also.
This is needed mostly for widgets, plugins or advertising, but would work for your case too. See [here](https://github.com/Unitadtechnologystandards/HTML5Lib/blob/master/localConnect/creative_localConnect.md).